# How can I start from current date in Date Picker using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

in my date picker month is starting from current month to next 12 months. Dates are showing from first date to last date. But I want to show current date to last date of current month. Past dates should not be shown. I think we can set a limit a, like i=dates.getDate() to start from current date. Not sure. Please check my fiddle and code.

```js
datepicker = angular.module('datepicker', []);

datepicker.controller('dateTimePicker', ['$scope', function($scope){
 console.log('alive');
        
  var date = new Date();
  var months = [],
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  $scope.year =2015;

  $scope.changeMonth = function(steps) {
    if ($scope.monthIndex + steps >= 0 &&
      $scope.monthIndex + steps <= 12
    ) {
      $scope.dateValues = [];
      $scope.monthIndex = $scope.monthIndex + steps;
      $scope.monthName = $scope.months[$scope.monthIndex];
       var date = new Date();
        console.log(date.getMonth());
        var offset = date.getMonth()
       console.log($scope.monthIndex);
        var offsetDate = offset + $scope.monthIndex;
      $scope.nDays = new Date( $scope.year,  offsetDate+1, 0).getDate();
        console.log(offsetDate+1);
        console.log(new Date( $scope.year, offsetDate, 1));
      for (i = 1; i <= $scope.nDays; i++) {  
     var d = new Date();
     $scope.dateValues.push(new Date($scope.year,  offsetDate, i));
     }
      
    }else{console.log("missed")}
  };

  $scope.monthIndex = 0;
  $scope.months = months;
  $scope.monthName = months[0];
  $scope.changeMonth(0);

}]);
```

fiddle link :- https://jsfiddle.net/enkode/89sbv65e/

Answer (score 1):

Change your `$scope.nDays` loop with the following which include comparasion of displayDate with current date, obviously you need to set time of `d` (current date) to 0 as your display date time is 0.

```
for (i = 1; i <= $scope.nDays; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var displayDate = new Date($scope.year,  offsetDate, i);
    if(displayDate >= d)
        $scope.dateValues.push(displayDate);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/89sbv65e/6/)

Comment: @cyberoy, is it what you want?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want. Thank you so much.